# Countdown Timer, timeLeftInMillis

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I don't understand this code's fragment about timer. Maybe someone explain me this 2 lines code?

```
int minutes= (int) (timeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
int seconds= (int) (timeLeftInMillis / (1000) % 60);
```

Comment: What do you understand about it? What don't you understand?

Comment: (and it's likely wrong, anyway)

Comment: I don't know why divide for 60 and % 60

Comment: Try supplying different values of `timeLeftInMillis`, and see what the resulting values of `minutes` and `seconds` are.

Answer (score 0):

If this is right, which I doubt, then the answer is:

```
int minutes = (int) (timeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
```

This line of code changes from miliseconds to minute and then divide minute with 60. The result is seconds left.

```
int seconds = (int) (timeLeftInMillis / (1000) % 60);
```

And this line of code divides miliseconds with modulo. When you divide 1000 with 60 what is get is the result of modulo. And when you divide miliseconds with this number, you get minutes left.

"(int)" just tells the data type. Result must be integer value.

Comment: Note that OP edited the question to reverse `minutes` and `seconds`.

Comment: It was my mistake

Comment: So when I divide for 60 I receive a minute and if I divide miliseconds with modulo I receive a seconds?

Comment: Please consider upvote or tick if answer was useful. thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you quotient which is seconds of timestamp.

```
int seconds = (int) (timeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
```

This will give you remainder of the timestamp . Which is minutes of timestamp;

```
int minutes = (int) (timeLeftInMillis / (1000) % 60);
```